# PHP exec rm -Rf not working for subdirectories

Tags: php, shell

I am trying to delete all contents in specific folder but it doesn't seem to effect subfolder but it should, because bash command does it from console.

```
system('rm -Rf some_dir/*');
```

Comment: It probably has something to do with bash expanding that asterisk.  Do you really want to remove all the files below some_dir without removing it?

Comment: is there a reason why youre not using recursive `unlink` and/or `rmdir` calls? `system` seems like overkill to me when you can't always guarantee it will be available to you...

Comment: I created bash script taking first argument as directory and then removing directories with bash.

Comment: if this is in a shell script then why do you need php do it in BASH :-)

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need in asterisk in this command. If you want to remove directory together with files, remove the slash as well. Leaving the slash will delete files, but preserve directory.

Also check comments on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: Not working for me. `rm -R somedir/` will remove directory with files

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the user executing the script doesn't have privileges for deleting the directory(ies) or the shell isn't in the right directory.

If you're running this via apache, chances are the process is owned by www-data. If the "some_dir" directory doesn't allow for write access by www-data, then it won't work.

Since you're using a relative path (very dangerous), you need to ensure that the script is executing in the correct directory. I'd suggest you change the path to an absolute one if you can - "rm -rf /path/to/some_dir".

Comment: I would rather say that apache and php scripts run as the user "nobody". So make sure to "chown -R nobody:users DIRNAME".