# php rm -rf not work using exec to remove a 777 folder

Tags: php, apache, exec, chmod, rm

ENV:
xampp(php 5.3)
centos 6.0
"rm -rf" not work for me.

```
$directory="$folder/$subfolder"
exec("rm -rf $directory");
```

I want to remove subfolder. $folder is an absolute path. **$folder** and **$subfolder** is a `777` folder.
when I echo `whoami` in php using `exec`, I got daemon. When I run `su daemon` in shell, I got `This account is currently not available.` links [PHP exec rm -Rf not working for subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587404/php-exec-rm-rf-not-working-for-subdirectories) is not helpful. What could that be? Thanks.

**Edit**
There is special characters in the argument. Now I am doing this.

```
exec("rm -rf ".escapeshellarg("directory"));
```

Results of echo seems correctly.

```
rm -rf '/absolute/path/to/folder/tspfolder b'
```

Comment: What happens if you echo the string you are running through exec, and run that string directly.

Comment: There is special characters in folder name.